# How to derive the Dilogarithm reflection $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln(x)\ln(1-x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reflection, polylogarithm

While exploring some interesting sums involving the harmonic numbers, I stumbled onto a useful identity for the Dilogarithm.
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln(x)\ln(1-x)$$

I tried using the sum formula for the Dilogarithm and combining $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)$ but had no success. I would be very grateful if anybody could show me how this reflection formula is derived.

Comment: Differentiate & verify this is true, then integrate to obtain the original formula.